.NET Aspire - can't connect to database with volume `WithVolume()`
I'm trying to create database with volume to have persist data in .NET Aspire. My connection string seems correct but I got error of password authentication failed. Everything worked fine until i used WithVolume().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 28P01: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
         at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessageLong(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.AuthenticateSASL(List`1 mechanisms, String username, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Authenticate(String username, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|213_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
         at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.<Get>g__RentAsync|34_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|42_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Ardalis.Specification.EntityFrameworkCore.RepositoryBase`1.ListAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at AspireSample.ApiService.Features.Templates.GetList.GetListQueryHandler.HandleInternal(GetListQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\AspireSample\AspireSample\AspireSample.ApiService\Features\Templates\GetList\GetListQueryHandler.cs:line 23
         at AspireSample.ApiService.Features.BaseHandlers.QueryHandlerBase`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\AspireSample\AspireSample\AspireSample.ApiService\Features\BaseHandlers\QueryHandlerBase.cs:line 20
         at AspireSample.ApiService.Features.Templates.TemplateModule.<>c.<<AddRoutes>b__0_5>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\AspireSample\AspireSample\AspireSample.ApiService\Features\Templates\TemplateModule.cs:line 47
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<ExecuteTaskOfT>g__ExecuteAwaited|133_0[T](Task`1 task, HttpContext httpContext, JsonTypeInfo`1 jsonTypeInfo)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
        Exception data:
          Severity: FATAL
          SqlState: 28P01
          MessageText: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
          File: auth.c
          Line: 323
          Routine: auth_failed

I define database in AppHost:
var postgresPassword = builder.AddParameter("postgresql-password", true);
var db = builder.AddPostgres("db", password: postgresPassword).WithDataVolume().WithPgAdmin();
var templateApiDb = db.AddDatabase("templateApiDb");

var apiService = builder.AddProject<Projects.AspireSample_ApiService>("apiservice")
    .WithReference(templateApiDb);

And I call it in my ApiService like this:
builder.AddNpgsqlDbContext<AppDbContext>("templateApiDb");

ConnectionString which I can see in ApiProject is:
ConnectionStrings__templateApiDb: Host=localhost;Port=58967;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=templateApiDb
And for database container I have same user and same password. Port for database is also 58967 bude tcp target port is 58979, but that targer port is always changing.
I didn't find anything in documentation.

The error  password authentication failed for user "postgres" says the password is wrong. I don't see how this is related to Aspire. Have you tried to connect to the database with eg pgAdmin ?

but password is correct. So I'm asking if i should do something else with implementation. My DB worked with Aspire, until I added volume.

PgAdmin same error. Wrong password but password I know is correct. So something is wrong with that configuration database with volume or something.

So the password is most definitely NOT correct

Okay, so how can I set password for DB differently ? because I set it by documentation to "postgres". In connection string I can see that it is "postgres". In docker I can see that POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres but when i try type as password in pgadmin "postgres" its not correct. But Aspire should transfer this credence to project which use that db.

I think I have to add something to that and I dont know what because password IS correct in connectionStrings which are sent do database and api which should use api.

Your own code passes the parameter postgresql-password, not postgresql_password. The official PostgreSQL Docker image uses POSTGRES_PASSWORD. The code never passes a custom password to the database. Worse, your code sets the parameter to true, not an actual password. If you don't specify anything, Aspire will create a default user, random password and pass those to EF.

Have you tried going through the steps in the PostgreSQL -EF Core Components docs without modifying them? It's a lot easier to first test using the unmodified templates or tutorials before trying to customize

That said, the docs should show how to specify the username and password. It's a very common step and just 3-4 lines of extra docs

What ? var postgresPassword = builder.AddParameter("postgresql-password", true); means that you create parameter name "postgresql-password" and that true means true for secret. You set password in command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/fundamentals/persist-data-volumes.
But thats not the problem. As I said in docker I can see in ENV that POSTGRES_PASSWORD equal the same password as is in my connectionString which Aspire generated. And If I use in pgadmin that password which is in ENV in docker I got the same message Incorrect password.

As i said I tried that sample. I customized it, everything worked, but when i used that '.WithDataVolume()' which are creating volume in database I started getting this type of error.

Have you ever tried something complex with .NET Aspire ?

Yes. And Docker. And searched to find how to actually specify the user and password in PostgreSQL docker images. What I haven't seen is your docker file and the settings you refer to. Where did you find postgresql-password or that it should be set to true? Have you tried AddParameter("POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "postgres");

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/fundamentals/persist-data-volumes
Here, I sent you that

Put that in the question itself, highlighting the relevant part, which comes at the very end. Post enough so others can reproduce the problem. Including what you tried and when errors started. People aren't obliged to start googling just to understand your question. Had you said that things worked before using WithDataVolume I wouldn't search for the obvious problem of incorrect image password

Im not sure is this still relevant because of the https://github.com/dotnet/aspire/issues/4461
But I have found a strange (actually not, but it took some hour to figure out) behaviour with DataVolumes in Aspire, especially when you doing with a lot of "playgrounds or versions of a repositories for projects"
So, here it is:
if a data volume was already created with some "password" and then you introduce new password through the aspire API like a parameter. Then Aspire does its job and passes new cstring everywhere, but you would have "incorrect password" problems.
Solution: rename the volume by providing the string with a data volume name
